# ReactJS, Same Component, Toggle out class from other component onClick

Tags: javascript, animation, reactjs

so I have a Main.jsx parent file, that takes two of the same component, but with different data attached to it. The Child component has a button with an onClick.

**Main.jsx**

```
    class Main extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                    <Child
                        styleName="pane-1 text-center"
                        title="Title 1"
                        description="Some Text"
                    />
                    <Child
                        styleName="pane-2 text-center"
                        title="Title 2"
                        description="Some Text"
                    />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Main
```

**Child.jsx**

```
class Child extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={classnames('pane', this.props.colName)}>
                <div className={classnames(this.props.styleName)}>
                    <div className="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>
                        <p>{this.props.description}</p>
                        <button onClick={this.togglePane} className="btn btn-primary-outline">Tell Me More</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Child
```

Now, in the above Child.jsx file the colName props is what needs to change, but only for the component that the user clicks the button on.

I tried the following in the Child.jsx file as well, but this does not seem to work, and from what I've read, its better to keep most components stateless as well:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            colName: 'col-sm-6'
        };

        this.togglePane = this.togglePane.bind(this);
    }
    togglePane() {
       if (this.state.colName == 'col-sm-6'){
           this.setState({colName: 'col-sm-4'})
       } else {
           this.setState({colName: 'col-sm-6'})
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be handled at the parent. Parent can make one be sm-8 and other be sm-4.

```
<button onClick={this.props.togglePane} />
```

In the parent, handle it

```
<Child
  styleName="pane-1 text-center"
  colName={this.state.firstCol}
  togglePane={this.togglePane}                     
/>
<Child
  styleName="pane-2 text-center"
  colName={this.state.secondCol}
  togglePane={this.togglePane}                     
/>

togglePane() {
  if(this.state.firstCol==='col-sm-6') {
    this.setState({ firstCol: 'col-sm-8', secondCol: 'col-sm-4' });
  } else {
    this.setState({ firstCol: 'col-sm-6', secondCol: 'col-sm-6' });
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you for that. Just FYI, so I've got two separate toggles, i.e. for the firstCol, and the secondCol, do you think the best way to do it is by having two separate togglePaneLeft() and togglePaneRight() with if statements to toggle them separately?

Comment: yes, something like that will be easier and neater. otherwise there will be too many if's.

Comment: Ok great, thank you for your help Vijay! Also, not sure if I should make another question or not, but I'm also trying to replace the second child element, with a totally different element when the first toggle is clicked, and vice versa, I've found a way to do it using an if statement in the render() method, but that will be really messy. Do you think a better idea would be to have a separate container altogether with the relevant divs on it and then add a link to that page instead?

Comment: Show / hide can be accomplished by state on the parent. Both can be placed adjacent with one of them hidden always.